# Give me solution for fast searching among million record from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table with million records.

i already indexed column name which i want to search from keywords.

i am using codeigniter PHP framework and apply below code for searching

```
if(str_word_count($search_text['name']) == 1 || str_word_count($search_text['name']) == 2){
            $search_text = substr($search_text['name'],0,4);
            $this->db->like('name',$search_text);
        }else{
            $this->db->like('name',$search_text['name']);
        }
```

i tried various database operation like indexing , table normalization

before i normalized table size was in GB's. yes i know that was worst but now my primary table size is 300 mb only and other normalized table have large data.  And important thing in my primary table million records where i am using search but its getting slower.

Please give help me.

Comment: What is your index types? Like queries are getting slow by size of your tables.

Comment: index type is VARCHAR for name and primary key type is bigint

Comment: Try FULLTEXT index.

Comment: hey i tried with fulltext index it was fast but when i apply condition order by it is getting slow search